# SQL Loop through table of tables names and insert

Tags: sql-server, ssis

As part of a SSIS package I have a SQL table containing the staging table name and corresponding 'real' table name.  The staging table names will change based on the date but there is a previous step that works out what the Real_Table is.

How do I loop through each one in SQL and insert all the data from the staging tables (columns are identical in both) into the real table and update the flag from 0 to 1 to mark it was done.  This is my table:

```
Staging_Table            Real_Table     UpdateFlag
Customers_01012018       Customers      0
Order_01012018           Order          0
Suppliers_02022018       Suppliers      0
```

Comment: With dynamic sql and a cursor.

Comment: By "inserting columns", I assume you actually mean inserting rows and not issuing `ALTER TABLE ... ADD` statements to add columns? You may want to clear that up in the description. Also, do the destination tables already contain rows that need to be updated or possibly even removed, or is this going to insert data only? If the tables need to be replaced in their entirety, using `sp_rename` to swap them in is far more efficient.

Comment: Why "in SQL"?    Why not in SSIS?

Comment: amended description. How would you do this in SSIS?

Comment: Procedural would be just as flexible as SSIS, which you could in turn call within an SSIS package. @scsimon is correct dynamic SQL and cursors would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use while loop to load the data into Real tables,

```
DECLARE @total INT
DECLARE @start INT
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @staging_table NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @real_table NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @start = 1
SET @total = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Stg_tables)

WHILE(@start <= @total)
BEGIN

    SELECT TOP 1 @staging_table = Staging_Table, @real_table = Real_Table FROM Stg_tables WHERE UpdateFlag = 0
    SET @query = 'INSERT INTO ' + @real_table + ' SELECT * FROM ' + @staging_table

    EXEC(@query)

    UPDATE Stg_tables SET UpdateFlag = 1 WHERE Staging_Table = @staging_table AND Real_Table = @real_table

    SET @start = @start + 1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

An overview of how to go about this is below.  Of course make sure to match the correct configurations to your environment and set the metadata appropriately where applicable.

- Create an Execute SQL Task that selects the staging and real table
  names.  Choose the "Full result set" `ResultSet`.  On the Result Set
  page, add an object variable and set the Result Name to 0 to use the
  immediate results.
- Add a `Foreach Loop` that is of the `Foreach ADO Enumerator` type.  Use the object variable from the Execute SQL Task as the ADO Object Source Variable.  On the Variable Mappings page, add a string variable at index 1 and 0.  One of these will hold the staging table name and the other will hold the real table name.  These will align with the order they were selected in the Execute SQL Task, so if you selected the staging table first there use a the variable that will hold this name at index 0.
- Create another string variable that contains an expression selecting the necessary columns that will be loaded from the staging table with the variable holding this table name concatenated within in.  An Example of this follows with the `@[User::StagingTableVariable]` variable representing the variable holding the staging table name.
- Within the Foreach Loop, add Data Flow Task then add an OLE DB Source inside this.  This will use the variable with the SQL selecting from the staging table, but to correctly set the metadata choose the SQL Command option and use a SQL statement that selects the same columns from an existing staging table name.  Once this is set, change the `ValidateExternalMetadata` property to false, choose "SQL command from variable" for the Data Access Mode, and pick the variable holding the SQL statement that uses the staging table name.
- Add an OLE DB Destination and connect the source to this.  Like before, use an existing real table and map the columns.  After this, again set `ValidateExternalMetadata` to false, change Data Access Mode to the use a table or view name from variable (I would recommend the fast load option), and add the variable holding the real table name.
- After the Data Flow Task add another Execute SQL Task that's linked to the DFT.  Create a string variable with an update statement for the mapping table where the table names originate from.  Set the `SQLSourceType` value to variable and select this variable for the `SourceVariable` property.  If you're using a text column in the `WHERE` clause of the update statement, make sure that the expression contains single quotes (`'`) as a typical SQL update statement would.

**Example OLE DB Source Variable Expression:**

```
"SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC from YourSchema."  +  @[User::StagingTableVariable]
```

**Example Variable Expression Update Command:**

```
"UPDATE YourSchema.MappingTable SET UpdateFlag = 1 where Real_Table = '" +  @[User::RealTableVariable] + "'"
```